# How to add a variable in ajax URL route

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am trying to concatenate a variable to my url link in ajax. The variable `$news` is the one that handles the notification id.

```
$(document).on("click", "#viewList", function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var $news = $(this).prop("value");
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url : '{{url("admin/recipients/", $news)}}', //returning an error undefined variable news
        data: {newsID : $news},
        success: function(store) {
            console.log(store);
            $('#rec').text(store);
        },
        error: function() {
          $('.alert').html('Error occured. Please try again.');
        }
    });

});
```

In my web.php, it's route is inside a route group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/recipients/{news}', 'Admin\NewsController@recipients');
    });
});
```

So how can I make this work? By the way, my ajax is inside a `blade.php` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$news doesnt exist to blade because it executes on the time server is rendering the page. So your javascript hasn't been executed yet. To make this work, change you js code to this:

```php
$(document).on("click", "#viewList", function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var news = $(this).prop("value");
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url : '{{url("admin/recipients")}}' + '/' + news,
        data: {newsID : news},
        success: function(store) {
            console.log(store);
            $('#rec').text(store);
        },
        error: function() {
          $('.alert').html('Error occured. Please try again.');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Error : `GET https://localhost/admin/recipients12?newsID=12 404 (Not Found)` it should be 'https://localhost/admin/recipients/12?newsID=12'. Missing `/`

Comment: Yes, you will have to add this on your js , so instead of just `'{{url("admin/recipients/")}}' + news`, you'll have to do `'{{url("admin/recipients")}}' + '/' + news`. I guess it is because url blade function is removing the last `/`.